# Document Set content type shared column

Tags: document-set

I have created a document set content type that has multiple columns. One of those columns is "Tracking Number," and it is a shared column. I want to know if it is possible for users to edit the value of the "Tracking Number" column in the document that inherits the value from the document set.

Kind Regards

Comment: Short answer is yes, please see: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/document-set-issue-shared-columns-does-not-update-when-moving/m-p/1438202
And: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/edit-column-data-in-sharepoint-library/m-p/3677211